# How to call a controller method to populate partial on root page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've got a controller method:

```
def latest_blogs
  @latest_blogs = BlogEntry.all.order('dato DESC').limit(4)
end
```

A root html.erb file which acts as my home page:

```
<div class="body-box">
  <div class="body-content">
    <%= render :partial => 'blog_list' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The blog_list partial:

```
<div class="blog-list">
  <%= latest_blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <%= render :partial => "blog_preview",  locals: {blog: blog} %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And the blog_preview partial which is just a stub for now:

```
<div class="blog-preview">
 <%= blog.title %>
</div>
```

My routes.rb entries:

```
resources :blog_entries
root :to => 'home#blog_home', :as => 'root'
```

How can I tell my app when it loads the root page to present `latest_blogs`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with: this method should not be in the controller. Put it in a model instead

```
class BlogEntry < ActiveDirectory::Base
  def self.latest (n = 4)
    all.order('dato desc').limit(n)
  end
```

Then just use it as:

```
BlogEntry.latest
```

Note that this method will also be available on relations:

```
user.blog_entries.latest(1)   #=> returns last user blog entry
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `latest_blog` as helper method.  Please try the following:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  def latest_blogs
    @latest_blogs = BlogEntry.all.order('dato DESC').limit(4)
  end

  helper_method :latest_blogs
end
```

Comment: I've tried this and all the methods listed below but now I get this error in all cases:  `QLite3::SQLException: no such column: dato: SELECT  "blog_entries".* FROM "blog_entries"   ORDER BY dato desc LIMIT 4`

Comment: @JoeEssey, please check your model/table, do you have `dato` field?

Comment: @JoeEssey, yeah it happens sometimes :).

Answer (score 1):

Is latest_blogs your actual controller action, or is it just some method you're exposing to the view?  If it's just some method you're exposing then you should make it a helper method.

```
def latest_blogs
  @latest_blogs ||= BlogEntry.all.order('dato DESC').limit(4)
end
helper_method :latest_blogs
```

Note that I changed the = to ||= in here.  I think that's better in this case so that if you happen to call the helper multiple times then it won't re-evaluable it repeatedly.

And FYI, you can also clean up your markup code a little bit.  Your root html file could do:

```
<div class="body-box">
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="blog-list">
      <%= render partial: 'blog_preview', collection: latest_blogs %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then _blog_preview.html.erb:

```
<div class="blog-preview">
  <%= blog_preview.title %>
</div>
```